# Sencha View not changing on Click Event

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to develop an application with will call REST Servive from Sencha using Ext.Ajax.

I am successfully able to get response, but when am trying to load the different view, nothing is happening.

I have taken Reference of  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185667/how-to-open-a-new-view-on-button-click-in-sencha-touch-2) .

**App.js**

Ext.application({
    name: 'epsoft',

```
requires: [
    'Ext.MessageBox',
    'Ext.Ajax',
    'Ext.Container'
],

views: [
    'Main','admin','login',
],

launch: function() {
    // Destroy the #appLoadingIndicator element
    Ext.fly('appLoadingIndicator').destroy();

    // Initialize the main view
    Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('epsoft.view.login'));
},
```

)}

Under **LoginController.js**

```
Ext.Msg.alert('title', 'Failure');
Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('epsoft.view.admin'));
```

The Msg Pop-up is coming properly , but the new view is not loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the new view as the activeitem to viewport, try this

> Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(Ext.Viewport.add({xtype: 'admin'}));

Here I am assuming admin is the xtype of your next view.

Comment: Thanks Ram , this also works. But can you please tell me what is the difference between two ?? it will help me understand better.

Comment: This is the recommended method, using viewport adds div tags for the view that you are trying to create which is common to both our answers but in your case the view that you want to show is in the background, you are destroying the current view(the current viewport's active item) which shows the view you had just created. The problem with this approach is when you are trying to go back in which case you cannot since you have destroyed the view that you would want to show while going back. I hope i was clear if not i will elucidate further

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure is this the proper way to do it, but i try this :

Let say your **login.js** has id under config part ,similar to below example :

```
Ext.define('epsoft.view.login', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'login',
    config: { 
        id: 'loginForm', // here is ID
        items: [ 
                     . . . 
               ]
     }
});
```

then under your **loginController.js** ,you can launch the new view by :

```
 var paneltab = Ext.create('epsoft.view.admin'); //Mention the view name to launch
 Ext.getCmp('loginForm').destroy(); // Destroying the ID
 Ext.Viewport.add(paneltab); // add to the ViewPort
```

Hope it will be usefull.